# Create a column in Pandas by summing and multiplying the previous value in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I think that my problem is best illustrated with an example.

The following are the columns I have as inputs.

```
Month       Monthly_Interest    Payment_Shortfall      Amount_In_Arrears
1               0.1             20                     
2               0.1             100                    
3               0.1             105                    
4               0.1             50                     
5               0.1             5                      
6               0.1             30                     
7               0.1             70
```

This is the output that I need.

```
Month       Monthly_Interest    Payment_Shortfall      Amount_In_Arrears
1               0.1             20                     20.00
2               0.1             100                    122.00
3               0.1             105                    239.20
4               0.1             50                     313.12
5               0.1             5                      349.43
6               0.1             30                     414.38
7               0.1             70                     525.81
```

This is a loan which is being underpaid each month by the `Payment_Shortfall`.

The `Payment_Shortfall` builds up each month to form the `Amount_In_Arrears`.

Interest is charged on the `Amount_In_Arrears` as at the previous month and is added to the current month's `Amount_In_Arrears`.

In other words: `Amount_In_Arrears =  Payment_Shortfall + Amount_In_Arrears(previous month) + Amount_In_Arrears(previous month) * Monthly_Interest`

For example, for month 2:  `Amount_in_Arrears = 100 + 20 + 20 * 0.1 = 122` and for month 3: `Amount_in_Arrears = 105 + 122 + 122 * 0.1 = 239.20`

I have been trying to do this in Pandas and I just can't seem to figure it out. I will need to apply it to a fairly large dataframe (about 3 million rows), so efficiency is a consideration.

My data have a number of loans like this, so I will also need the solution to reset (probably using the groupby() function), however, I think it's best to deal with one issue at a time.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Well Its better you post text that image, and how final output should look like

Comment: Thank you, I have updated per your comment. I hope that it is easier to follow now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no efficient way to calculate this in plain pandas(But if there is, I'd very much like to know). I know of two options to get fast computations in python for this kind of task, [cython](http://cython.org/) (specially annotated python that is compiled to c) and [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) (a just in time compiler for plain python).

Since i don't know much about cython I'll give you the example for numba.

For numba you write a separate function with a numba decorater. Numba plays nice with numpy but doesn't know pandas, therefore we have to feed numpy arrays into the function:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def compute_total_amount(interest, amount):
  n = len(interest)
  total_amount = np.empty(n)
  total_amount[0] = amount[0]
  for i in range(1,n):
    total_amount[i] = total_amount[i-1]*(1+interest[i])+amount[i]
  return total_amount

df['Amount_In_Arrears'] = compute_total_amount(df['Monthly_Interest'].values,\
                                               df['Payment_Shortfall'].values)

   Payment_Shortfall  Monthly_Interest  Amount_In_Arrears
0                 20               0.1           20.00000
1                100               0.1          122.00000
2                105               0.1          239.20000
3                 50               0.1          313.12000
4                  5               0.1          349.43200
5                 30               0.1          414.37520
6                 70               0.1          525.81272
```

EDIT: Added timings for numba vs plain python (1m rows)

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Payment_Shortfall':np.random.random(10**6)*10}))
df['Monthly_Interest'] = -0.01

def compute_total_amount_python(interest, amount):
  n = len(interest)
  total_amount = np.empty(n)
  total_amount[0] = amount[0]
  for i in range(1,n):
    total_amount[i] = total_amount[i-1]*(1+interest[i])+amount[i]
  return total_amount

%timeit compute_total_amount_python(df['Monthly_Interest'].values, df['Payment_Shortfall'].values)
729 ms ± 36.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit compute_total_amount(df['Monthly_Interest'].values, df['Payment_Shortfall'].values)
2.7 ms ± 62.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```